# how to subset a list based on ascending/descending order of a column vector in R

Tags: r

How to subset a list based on a column vector satisfying ascending order condition in R?

I have a list with 30 objects, where in each object there are 4 columns. i would like to subset/ split the list by checking if 3rd column in each object is in either ascending order or descending order. if the 3rd column vector of 2nd, 4th, 11th, 16th, 19th, 21st etc objects are in ascending order, then subset the list.

the sample data that i have is shown as follows

```
A <- c(477.119,469.483,42.1,453.912,447.7579,41.6,435.2942,429.2672,42.9352)
B <- c(106.98, 106.7397,10.748,106.563,106.646,106.9,106.812,106.98,17.08)
C <- c(10.804,11.108,11.402,11.780,12.033,12.302,12.59634,12.88163,13.19987)
D <- c(10.28718,10.65794,11.02,11.42,11.773,12.11,12.473,12.82436,13.19136)

a1 <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)

A1 <- c(195.5,16.4776,19.408,198.3052,19.2327,20.2429,21.2545,20.3428)
B1 <- c(114.155,114.197,114.239,114.28,114.322,114.364,114.405,114.447)
C1 <- c(41.85957,41.623,41.410,41.205,40.99,40.766,40.540,40.29467)
D1 <- c(31.42653,31.27387,31.129,30.981,30.844,30.6982,30.53915,30.38037)

b1 <- data.frame(A1, B1, C1, D1)

A2 <- c(150.42,11.66,12.95,14.31,15.79,17.531,19.226,11.1279)
B2 <- c(11.724,1.766,11.808,11.849,11.891,11.933,11.975,12.016)
C2 <- c(56.226,55.007,54.0772,53.3295,52.7034,52.1328,51.696,51.3063)
D2 <- c(41.409,40.113,39.228,38.4687,37.83086,37.24863,36.801,36.401)

c1 <- data.frame(A2, B2, C2, D2)
mydata <- list(a1, b1, c1)
```

from the data presented above, in object [[a1]]'s Cth column vector is in ascending order while the other two objects are in descending order. so i am looking for a code to check the condition on each object's Cth column vector and split the list. for this, i have tried with the following code but not working.

Note: in the Cth/3rd column vector, when it is a large vector, very few values do not follow the order

first i tried to check for the 1st object in my list

```
is.ordered(mydata$a1[3])
```

i am getting the result as:

```
False
```

the same result is coming for other objects too... which is not true

```
for (i in seq_along(mydata)){
    if (is.ordered(i[3]) <- TRUE) {
      mydata1 <- mydata[i]
    else
      mydata2 <- mydata[i]
  }
}
```

this is not working

the expected result is as follows

```
mydata1
[[a1]]
A           B               C               D
477.1149    106.6898314 10.80482    10.28718
469.4843    106.7315397 11.10778    10.65794
42.1        10.773248   11.40281    11.02817
453.9212    106.8149563 11.78007    11.42233
447.7579    106.8566646 12.03301    11.773
41.6        106.8983729 12.30212    12.11687
435.2942    106.9400812 12.59634    12.47315
429.2672    106.9817895 12.88163    12.82436
42.9352      17.0234978 13.19987    13.19136

mydata2
[[b1]]
A           B               C               D
195.5   114.1556171 41.85957    31.42653
16.4776 11.1973254  41.62823    31.27387
19.408  11.2390337  41.41062    31.12951
198.30  14.280742   41.20588    30.98881
19.2327 11.3224503  40.9934     30.84694
20.2429 11.3641586  40.76652    30.69182
21.2545 4.4058669   40.54016    30.53915
20.3428 114.4475752 40.29467    30.38037
203.48  114.4892835 40.04356    30.21333

[[c1]]
A           B             C             D
150.42  11.7248034  56.22614    41.40349
11.6695 1.7665117   55.00748    40.16213
12.9522 11.80822    54.07732    39.22808
14.3145 14.8499283  53.32955    38.4687
15.7921 11.8916366  52.70304    37.83086
17.5311 11.9333449  52.13248    37.24863
19.226  11.9750532  51.69696    36.80191
11.1279 12.0167615  51.30663    36.40155
12.3976 12.0584698  51.07735    36.19506
```

Comment: Please include sample data in a reproducible format using `dput`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers i have presented the data in reproducible format....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want (or not?)

```
idx <- c()
for (k in seq_along(mydata)){
  if (!is.unsorted(mydata[[k]]$C)) idx <- c(idx, k)
}
mydata.ascending <- mydata[idx]
mydata.descending <- mydata[-idx]
```

Using `!is.unsorted` to judge if column is ascending

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding the posted answer is not working when specifying column number ..... i.e. instead of column name, i would like to use column number ???? thanks in advance

Comment: @Kumar try to replace `!is.unsorted(mydata[[k]]$C` with `!is.unsorted(mydata[[k]][,colnum]`, where `colnum` can be specified

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774825/3277821), you can use `all` and `diff` to check if column `C` in a data frame element is in ascending order.  `sapply` is used to iterate over each data frame in the list and returns a boolean vector that is `TRUE` when `C` is in acending order

```r
mydata <- list(
  a = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = runif(10), C = rev(1:10)),
  b = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = runif(10), C = 1:10),
  c = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = runif(10), C = sample(1:10, 10)),
  d = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = runif(10), C = 1:10)
)

mydata[sapply(mydata, function(x) all(diff(x$C) >= 0))]
#> $b
#>             A          B  C
#> 1  -0.1266213 0.39444137  1
#> 2  -0.2983481 0.69384799  2
#> 3  -1.0826327 0.51337491  3
#> 4   0.1082822 0.62529737  4
#> 5   0.4650216 0.20580597  5
#> 6   0.4129133 0.10899147  6
#> 7   1.6014768 0.88541775  7
#> 8   0.7889176 0.99494885  8
#> 9   0.2097572 0.68434466  9
#> 10 -2.2161454 0.03854874 10
#> 
#> $d
#>             A         B  C
#> 1  -0.1674129 0.1282160  1
#> 2   1.6887421 0.6871053  2
#> 3  -1.2915220 0.5023277  3
#> 4   0.6181605 0.8020529  4
#> 5  -1.0125448 0.4254577  5
#> 6   0.6019005 0.2033730  6
#> 7  -0.6954242 0.3959902  7
#> 8  -2.0667610 0.8642022  8
#> 9  -1.4052872 0.1155380  9
#> 10  1.3859010 0.5984434 10
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: the posted answer doesn't work when used for removing duplicated rows based on a specific column in a list of data frames.....i used the following code for removing duplicated rows: mydata1 <- mydata[sapply(mydata, function(x) x[,unique(x$Time)])].... i am getting the following error: " Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , unique(x$Time)) : undefined columns selected "

Comment: using the following code, it worked ...mydata1 <- lapply(mydata, function(x) x[!duplicated(x$Time),])....

Comment: how to specify column number to the code posted? "mydata[sapply(mydata, function(x) all(diff(x$C) >= 0))]"... i would like to use column number instead of name??? thanks in advance

Comment: ok I understand but removing duplicated rows was not a part of your original question.  Glad you found a solution that works for you.